# Xamarin Forms - webkit in a content page

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to display a page in a **Xamarin.Forms** content page.  I have the `webview` setup on a **Xaml** page.

My **Xaml** page is literally just a `WebView`.  I can't paste it in because its getting caught in the editor.

My .cs file looks like:

```
iHud hud;
Int64 _TournamentId;
public Scoreboard(Int64 TournamentId)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _TournamentId = TournamentId;
    hud = DependencyService.Get<iHud>();
}

protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(wv.Source)))
    {
        hud.Show();
        var sUrl = await MobileSupport.ws.ScorecardScoreboardAsync(_TournamentId); // this returns the url that I need to load.
        hud.Dismiss();
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            wv.Source = sUrl.Uri;
        });
    }
}
private void wv_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    hud.Dismiss();
}
private void wv_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    hud.Show();
}
```

My first error occurs when I try to load the web content the first time:

> 2020-11-30 13:14:09.000519-0500 Scorecards.iOS[33822:2847938] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=33822
> 2020-11-30 13:14:09.000842-0500 Scorecards.iOS[33822:2847938] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: Scorecards.iOS[33822]/0#-1 LF=0
> 2020-11-30 13:14:09.043613-0500 Scorecards.iOS[33822:2847141] [unspecified] container_system_group_path_for_identifier: error = ((container_error_t)98) NOT_CODESIGNED
> 2020-11-30 13:14:09.043748-0500 Scorecards.iOS[33822:2847141] [MC] Error getting system group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles: 98
> 2020-11-30 13:14:09.043968-0500 Scorecards.iOS[33822:2847141] [MC] Failed to get profile system group container path. Overriding with expected path: /Users/wallym/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EF5F2DBD-1B4F-4DEC-88C2-A4D5F94D0406/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

The next time that I try to load the scoreboard, I get this error:

> 2020-11-30 13:14:12.947337-0500 Scorecards.iOS[33822:2847141] [Process] 0x7ffa1cc49a20 - [pageProxyID=6, webPageID=7, PID=33840] WebPageProxy::processDidBecomeUnresponsive:
> 2020-11-30 13:37:23.995271-0500 Scorecards.iOS[33822:2847141] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}>
> 2020-11-30 13:37:23.995461-0500 Scorecards.iOS[33822:2847141] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11ccfebc0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID 33840, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}

The one thing that I want to mention is that I am returning a url that will then redirect the web browser to the appropriate place.  The url is secure.  It is on azure.

> https://wallytest.azurewebsites.net/PublicScores/ScoreboardRouter?TournamentId=5.

I've tried just about every dumb trick that I can think of to get this to display in a `WebView`, and it won't.  There is a request for geolocation that comes up sometimes in the `webview`, so I know that something is working.  Please don't mention the 404, that is after the page is loaded.

Any suggestions on getting this page to display are appreciated.

TIA

Comment: this displays for me on the first try - `<WebView Source="https://wallytest.azurewebsites.net/PublicScores/ScoreboardRouter?TournamentId=5" />`

Comment: Thanks @jason   I hard coded the site into my xaml, but it still won't load.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure why this issue is occurring.  However, I played with  how I am loading up the web browser.  I decided to play with the Xamarin Essentials Browser.OpenAsync(url); method.  It works perfectly.  Content loads, and I think it is ok.  I have to figure out how to display the hud during the load, but the content itself loads, which is good.

I'm putting the comment in here to provide an alternative option for future readers.